# IE8 - Odd behavior with head margin collapse on change in CSS "display"

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, margin

I have a strange issue where my head (`h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, etc.) margins are collapsing on me, but only in IE8.  I've spent a good deal of time trying to pinpoint the issue I am having, and have narrowed it down to this example.

I am almost completely certain that no other page objects can be removed (including the `DOCTYPE` declaration) while still representing this bug.  To make the code as compact as possible, the bug only appears after modifying the display property a couple of times, but the real page has an issue each time the display property is modified (i.e. immediately after any "nav" is followed).

I attempted posting this as a jsFiddle, but it was not reproduceable from the result pane.  Therefore, I will post the entire, simplified test case inline, written as small/clean as possible:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <title>Bug Test of IE8 Collapsing Margin problem</title>
   <style type="text/css">
      h2 {
         margin:                20px 0 15px -10px;
         background:            red;
      } h3 {
         margin:                10px 0 15px -10px;
         background:            green;
      } h4 {
         margin-bottom:         -15px;
         background:            blue;
      } .noShow {
         display:               none;
      }
   </style>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function show(theDiv) {
         theDiv   = document.getElementById(theDiv);
         Div1     = document.getElementById('div1');
         Div2     = document.getElementById('div2');
         Div1.style.display   = 'none';
         Div2.style.display   = 'none';
         theDiv.style.display = 'block';
      }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript: show('div1');">Nav1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript: show('div2');">Nav2</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="div1">
      <h1>Head1</h1>
      <h2>Head2</h2>
      <h3>Head3</h3>
      <h4>Head4</h4>
      <br><br>
      Click on "Nav2," then "Nav1," then "Nav2" a second time to see the shift
      in header margins/padding.<br>

   </div>
   <div id="div2" class="noShow">
      <h1>Head1</h1>
      <h2>Head2</h2>
      <h3>Head3</h3>
      <h4>Head4</h4>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've begun reading a bit about margin collapse and how it's supposed to act this way, but if that's the case, why is IE8 the only browser I've tested with this behavior, and why is it not consistent?  I've also tried switching margin with padding to achieve a similar result without the collapsing issue, but unless I did something incorrectly, that had no effect either.

I've tried applying `overflow:hidden` to the `noShow` declaration.  This fixes the problem, but I cannot use it in my design.  (Even when adjusting this in the example, it looks wrong and is still inconsistent in its placement.)

Does anyone have any good suggestions on how to work around this problem?  I'd hate to have to turn off my `DOCTYPE` and force IE7 mode, as I lose other features (such as pseudo-element `:before`).

Comment: IE8 does not work like IE7 which doesn't work like IE6 and none of those work like IE9 and NONE of them work like any other browser in the world. Having problems getting IE to work correctly is expected and the norm.

Comment: I understand that, but this looks more like a true "bug" than a CSS misinterpretation problem, since it is not consistent.  The code I've developed already works in IE 5.5/6/7 (IETester), and Firefox 3.6.  I'm sure it works in others, but that's all I have to test with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/7qymJ/1/

**Edit:**

http://jsfiddle.net/7qymJ/ - reproduces your error in IE8

Comment: Surprisingly, the combination of *both* `float: left` and `width:100%` appears to fix the problem.  However, I can't use `float:left` for my layout without significant changes.  Setting `width:100%` is acceptable, and I've already made that change.  Going to attempt other "haslayout" tricks to see if I have any luck.

Comment: @D.N use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left` and you should be fine.

Comment: `display:inline-block` almost always causes problems, but I'll give it a go and let you know. :)

Comment: @D.N. Understood but with the limited example code, it's hard to offer a solution that considers your entire site layout.

Comment: Damned if you do, damned if you don't on including code, I guess.  :)  I have other `float: right` elements that it conflicts with in all browsers but IE 5.5 (figures), so I'll have to continue to play.

Comment: @D.N. Post a live version of the site if the other elements on the page are of importance. This way we will be able to provide a better solution for your problem instead of fixing the example only to hear that it wont work due to other code on the page. Good luck!

Comment: I'm patient to keep playing, and I think I stumbled across something.  Surprisingly, changing the JS code to `display = "inline-block"` fixes most of the issue, but now I've got an issue with the internal container size that can't be fixed with a percentage *or* static width. Sigh...

Comment: I had to use a combination of a change in JS (to `display = "inline-block"`), a change in CSS (all head elements set to `width: 100%`), and HTML (putting all of the individual show/hide DIVs inside of yet another container div instead of assigning multiple classes to each).  But you pointed me to the most important two of those elements, and for that I am grateful!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640577/kyle) gave me the information I needed to get to my solution, and I have already accepted his solution, as he gave me the important parts to solve my specific case.  For ease of searching, I will post my specific solution here.

I made simple modifications to the CSS, JS, *and* HTML in combination to achieve my desired result.  Using the example I posted as a basis, I made the following changes:

```
h2, h3, h4 {
   ...
   width: 100%;
}

function show(theDiv) {
   ...
   theDiv.style.Display = "inline-block";
}
```

In addition, my specific example had a div with multiple class assignments:

```
<div id="div1" class="content">Initially Visible</div>
<div id="div2" class="content noShow">Initially Invisible</div>
```

I modified this by removing the multiple class assignments and creating (yet another) nested div:

```
<div class="content">
   <div id="div1">Initially Visible</div>
   <div id="div2" class="noShow">Initially Invisible</div>
</div>
```

The combination of all 3 elements (of which two were given to me by [Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640577/kyle), and the third was not included in my example posting) resulted in expected output.